Customize binder-environment for jupyter notebooks to display some text?
I have a few Jupyter Notebooks in a Github Repository that are often accessed through mybinder.org via link from people who are new to Python and don't have Jupyter Notebooks or any IDE for Python installed on their systems (yet). I thought it would be great if there was some kind of text or message added to the environment when people start it. So currently mybinder.org get's the link to my repo on Github and when the binder/jupyter-notebooks environments starts I see the list of files on my github in the sidebar to the left, and the Launcher in the main body. What I'd want is to simply add some text/html to the launcher to say something like "Welcome to this binder, you can find all the date in this github (link), have fun!" and then have the tiles where you can select a new Notebook etc. I'd also be happy with an alternative solution, as long as it's visible to uers.
I've been trying to find a solution for this for the last two days and am getting nowhere. I found some instructions to customize binder via a jupyer_notebooks_config.py, via postBuild- or start-files and I've tried them all, but none of it worked - when the environment is created by mybinder.org, it keeps displaying the default setup with no added text.
I have successfully implemented another repo that includes additional tiles to an OpenRefine environment, but I don't quite understand the mechanics in the background yet of how binderhub really builds the environment to adapt this to solve my current problem (this seems to work via github actions somehow). But since it's possible to add extra tiles, it must surely be possible to just squeeze in some addtional text?

You can open a particular notebook upon session start up with a well-crafted launch URL. In that initial notebook, you can use markdown and HTML in a markdown cell or cells to provide all sorts of guides to those interested in using your content via MyBinder-provided session. This is a rather open ended question that would benefit from extended conversation. The Jupyter Discourse forum has a 'Binder help' category were you can share your repo and discuss specifics.

There's quite a range of ways to do this:

the most direct is to craft your launch URL to open a specific notebook and use markdown/HTML there to to guide those interested in using your content. Launches from here have a thorough example illustrating this approach.
there is an extension called 'jupyterlab-tour'. (See note at end of next resource.)
see 'Show a floating panel' in the Jupyter Discourse forum, keeping in mind that Jupyter Notebook 7+ and JupyterLab are not both built on JupyterLab components and so a lot of the approaches you'll see around for JupyterLab, now apply to current in-development Jupyter Notebook. However, there may be differences that make things not as plug-and-play as you'd like between the two flavors.

